# diagnostics for a server that keeps turning off

Tags: supermicro

I have a 1U supermicro box that's a few years old and off-warranty. Recently it has begun randomly shutting down. It will stay up for anywhere from a few hours to a week and then stop responding. The IPMI console shows it as powered on but it's completely non-responsive.

I'd v much like to fix this machine as the owners are very budget constrained. It has CentOS 7 presently.

What I've looked for:

- IPMI logs - empty
- System logs - nothing relevant
- SAR - nothing interesting
- Hardware sensors - fans are on, CPU temp is nominal

What I've tried:

- supermicro [diagnostics](https://www.supermicro.com/solutions/SMS_SDO.cfm)  - the (UEFI) image won't boot properly on this system
- memtest+ - ran for 24 hours with no incident

Given that it has redundant power supplies Im thinking this isn't the issue. This leaves CPU and mainboard.

- What other tests can I run?
- What other log sources could I look into?
- What else might be failing?

---

### Edit:

Started up said machine and let it run until it quit (12 hours?). The IPMI window shows that it's stuck on the boot page of all things.

[image]

It had been booted and running. This makes me think it's a main board issue. There aren't any USB devices plugged in and it's well and truly wedged.

Comment: When the system freezes, do you have to hard power it off to recover, or is resetting it sufficient? Is the OS up to date?

Comment: I reset it via IPMI. Yes, the OS install is current.

Comment: Are the two PSUs getting power from the same source? Perhaps you're having brownouts...

Comment: The two PS are on different rails.

Comment: I suggest disabling console blanking (e.g. `setterm --blank 0` run on vt 1, or better yet, `consoleblank=0` on the kernel command line) just in case a panic does get logged to console. You'll then be able to see it in the IPMI virtual console the next time it happens.

Comment: Is there some way to log kernel panic / related to the system log? Something that would persist after reboot?

Comment: You can't reliably log a real kernel panic, because the kernel believes itself to be in such a state that it can't write to any disk or network reliably. In this case it will only write to the console (and a serial console if one is set up).

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to get a monitor connected. The datacenter trolls will get fussy if I tie up a crash cart for an extended period.

Comment: That's why God invented IPMI. You have no need to go to the physical console! You can view it remotely from the comfort of your workstation.

Comment: Your motherboard is well and truly hosed. Time to buy a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't completely rule out the PSU. If they're redundant, you could try running with only one, then the other.

Can you get replacement CPU(s)? Used Xeons are pretty cheap, and you can still sell them afterwards. If it's a multi CPU system, try removing all but one.

Does the system have a separate, replaceable VRM for the CPU?

It could well be the mainboard, but that probably means the machine is dead.

Comment: Are there any OS diagnostics for a mainboard? CPU?

Answer (score 2):

Use the process of elimination. Take out one component at a time:

1. Test if it crashes without each memory chip. If it doesn't crash then it's the memory chip that you took out
2. If it's not the ram, replace the hard drive with a temporary spare or boot off a live USB when you need to check the hard driver. If it doesn't power off then it's the hard disk
3. If the CPUs are removable, then you can try running without each one
4. Elimimate the power suppplies in the same way
5. If the NIC cards are removable eliminate that
6. If it's still an issue after all these tests then it's probably a fried motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm replying late, but for people that come across this in the future. I have a lot of experience with SuperMicro servers. If you want to definitely rule out the PSUs and PDBs, buy a PSU tester. Is it cheap and easy to use. I linked one from Amazon below but they're cheaper on eBay.

You plug the main 24-pin ATX connector and it powers the device up. If the PSU tester after some-time switches off, you know the issue is with the power source. If it remains on, then you can move onto checking if the issue is with the CPU, MOBO or DIMM. Usually a CPU or DIMM error will spit out an error on SEL.

Though to be safe, as @John M mentioned, boot the server with min config (only 1 CPU and 1 x DIMM) to rule out the DIMM. If the server has 2 CPUs you can install 1 in CPU0 slot and then swap them and also rule out the CPU. My guess is if the server is randomly crashing and you've ruled out the PSU/PDB and it is not producing any SEL, then good chance it is the MOBO.

Good luck iso-testing!

https://www.amazon.com.au/Computer-PC-Tester-Connectors-Enclosure/dp/B076CLNPPK?th=1

Answer (score -1):

Check dmesg for kernel panics etc also syslog might show you some hints assuming it’s related to the OS

Comment: You cannot run `dmesg` when the power is off.

Comment: Well I think that is plainly obvious :) the original query stated the server isn’t permanently down. It begins randomly shutting down and the OP does have the opportunity to inspect logs etc

Comment: If there is a kernel panic you won't be able to see it with `dmesg`. Besides a kernel panic doesn't cause the system to power off.

Comment: It can cause complete unresponsive system including on serial - also you can see a kernel panic in the logs I detailed. You are incorrect

Comment: A true kernel panic will not be logged anywhere except to console, as the kernel will be unable to send it anywhere else before it halts the system. But many kernel oopses do not rise to this level, and can be logged locally or across the network.

Comment: Precisely which is why it’s still worth checking the logs - thanks for the input @MichaelHampton